# Algorithm for rounding and clamping a number to specific ends

Tags: algorithm, numbers, rounding, clamp

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm that clamps an integer value within a range, while also changing its base10 end to one of multiple, variable length ends.

This should clamp a `value` between the `min` and `max`, while changing the end to one of the specific ends defined in `ends`, as close as possible to the original value.

Example input data:

```
ends: [26, 201, 330] (sorted list of integers, at least a factor 10 smaller than <value>)
min: 5350
max: 7392
```

`value: 2000` -> `5426`
`value: 6205` -> `6201`
`value: 7400` -> `7330`

I'll implement this in Go, but any pseudocode or other imperative language is also appreciated.

Comment: _I'm looking for an efficient algorithm_ [...] What have you tried? What problem are you facing?

Comment: It's trivial to create a simple solution that loops by clamping the value within the range, then adding/removing 1 every time, and then checking if it fits one of the rounding values, returning if it does. However, this is very inefficient for big numbers.

Comment: I wouldn't call those rounding values. It's how the string should end in base 10. If they were rounding values I would expect the result to be a multiple of that number.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I called it this because I thought it was easy to grok, but I've updated the question to use more correct terminology.

Comment: If you pass the ends as numbers you won't be able to enforce that the number ends in "00" (or more 0s), only "0" or you have to enforce a digit before it, but just 0s is not possible. I don't know if that is intended.

Comment: There might be better methods but if you don't have too many numbers in `ends` you can try computing the smallest prefix that would go with each `end` in `ends` that is between the desired range, then take the smallest overall number.

Comment: Binary search is it.

Comment: Shouldn't `7400` -> `7326`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you know how to clamp:

```
clamp(n, min, max) = max(min, min(max, n))
```

Then to remove the end and replace it with what it should end, you need the next higher power of 10:

```
nextPowerOf10(n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 10    // mathematically not correct but works here
    x = 1
    while (n > 0) {
        x = x * 10
        n = n / 10    // integer division
    }
    return x
}
```

So replacing the end of a number becomes simple:

```
replace(n, end) = n - n % nextPowerOf10(end) + end
```

Then you can check the other candidates on both sides, so when `m = replace(clamp(n, min, max), end)` and `p = nextPowerOf10(end)`, the other candidates are: `m - p` and `m + p`, everything put together:

```
clampEnd(n, min, max, end) {
    m = clamp(n, min, max)
    p = nextPowerOf10(end)
    m = m - m % p + end
    diff = -1
    ret = -1
    for (x in [m - p, m, m + p]) {
        // this rounds down, make abs(n - x) <= diff to round up on equal distance
        if (x >= min && x <= max && (diff < 0 || abs(n - x) < diff)) {
            diff = abs(n - x)
            ret = x
        }
    }
    return ret    // returns -1 if no number in range ends with end
}
```

Examples:

- 2000: m = clamp(2000, 5350, 7392) = 5350, p = nextPowerOf10(26) = 100, m = m - m % p + end = 5350 - 5350 % 100 + 26 = 5326, candidates = [m - p, m, m + p] = [5226, 5326, 5426], result = 5426 (only one in range).
- 6205: candidates = [5201, 6201, 7201] => 6201
- 7400: candidates = [6330, 7330, 8330] => 7330

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `ends` list isn't massive, it's probably simplest to pre-compute all the valid values between `vmin` and `vmax` and then binary search that list to find the closest value. You could implement that like this in python:

```py
import math

def expand_ends(ends, vmin, vmax):
    all_ends = []
    for end in ends:
        inc = 10 if end < 10 else 10 ** (int(math.log10(end)) + 1)
        v = vmin - vmin % inc + end
        if v < vmin:
            v += inc
        while True:
            if v > vmax:
                break
            all_ends.append(v)
            v += inc
    return sorted(all_ends)

def search(values, v):
    # check for end cases (clamp to range)
    # this simplifies the search as we don't need to worry about not
    # finding an insertion point in the list
    if v <= values[0]:
        return values[0]
    if v >= values[-1]:
        return values[-1]
    
    # binary search for closest value
    low = 0
    hi = len(values)
    while (low < hi):
        mid = (low + hi) // 2
        vmid = values[mid]
        if vmid < v:
            vmidp1 = values[mid+1]
            if vmidp1 > v:
                return vmid if (v - vmid) < (vmidp1 - v) else vmidp1
            low = mid + 1
        elif vmid > v:
            vmidm1 = values[mid-1]
            if vmidm1 < v:
                return vmid if (vmid - v) < (v - vmidm1) else vmidm1
            hi = mid
        else:
            return vmid
```

Usage:

```
ends = [26, 201, 330]
vmin, vmax = 5350, 7392
all_ends = expand_ends(ends, vmin, vmax)
# [5426, 5526, 5626, 5726, 5826, 5926, 6026, 6126, 6201, 6226, 6326, 6330, 6426, 6526, 6626, 6726, 6826, 6926, 7026, 7126, 7201, 7226, 7326, 7330]

search(all_ends, 2000)
# 5426
search(all_ends, 6205)
# 6201
search(all_ends, 6213)
# 6201
search(all_ends, 6214)
# 6226
search(all_ends, 6328)
# 6326
search(all_ends, 6329)
# 6330
search(all_ends, 7400)
# 7330
```

**Update**

I converted the other answer's code to python and used `timeit` to benchmark the two solutions iterating over every input from `vmin-100` to `vmin+100`:

```py
timeit.timeit(setup='''
import math
def expand_ends(ends, vmin, vmax):
    all_ends = []
    for end in ends:
        inc = 10 if end < 10 else 10 ** (int(math.log10(end)) + 1)
        v = vmin - vmin % inc + end
        if v < vmin:
            v += inc
        while True:
            if v > vmax:
                break
            all_ends.append(v)
            v += inc
    return sorted(all_ends)

def search(values, v):
    # check for end cases (clamp to range)
    # this simplifies the search as we don't need to worry about not
    # finding an insertion point in the list
    if v <= values[0]:
        return values[0]
    if v >= values[-1]:
        return values[-1]
    
    # binary search for closest value
    low = 0
    hi = len(values)
    while (low < hi):
        mid = (low + hi) // 2
        vmid = values[mid]
        if vmid < v:
            vmidp1 = values[mid+1]
            if vmidp1 > v:
                return vmid if (v - vmid) < (vmidp1 - v) else vmidp1
            low = mid + 1
        elif vmid > v:
            vmidm1 = values[mid-1]
            if vmidm1 < v:
                return vmid if (vmid - v) < (v - vmidm1) else vmidm1
            hi = mid
        else:
            return vmid

ends = [26, 201, 330]
vmin, vmax = 5350, 7392
''', stmt='''
all_ends = expand_ends(ends, vmin, vmax)
out = [search(all_ends, v) for v in range(vmin-100, vmax+100)]
''', number = 1_000)

timeit.timeit(setup='''
def nextPowerOf10(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 10    # mathematically not correct but works here
    x = 1
    while n > 0:
        x = x * 10
        n = n // 10    # integer division
    return x

def clampEnd(n, vmin, vmax, end):
    m = max(vmin, min(vmax, n))
    p = nextPowerOf10(end)
    m = m - m % p + end
    diff = -1
    ret = -1
    for x in [m - p, m, m + p]:
        # this rounds down, make abs(n - x) <= diff to round up on equal distance
        if vmin <= x <= vmax and (diff < 0 or abs(n - x) < diff):
            diff = abs(n - x)
            ret = x
    return ret    # returns -1 if no number in range ends with end

def bestEnd(v, ends):
    diffs = [abs(v-end) for end in ends]
    return ends[diffs.index(min(diffs))]

ends = [26, 201, 330]
vmin, vmax = 5350, 7392
''', stmt='''
out = [bestEnd(v, [clampEnd(v, vmin, vmax, end) for end in ends]) for v in range(vmin-100, vmax+100)]
''', number = 1_000)
```

On my computer, my solution takes 0.57 seconds while the other solution takes 4.56 seconds.

Comment: @Raven is computing a list of all possible ends not practical? If it is, then a binary search of that list is much faster than iterating the clamping procedure. When converting your code to python, my code runs almost 10x faster. See my edit